# C# - Get FieldInfo value from static readonly members of static classes using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to make a system that using reflection and during compilation time, it's able to generate a configuration file for some classes.
The usage of a configuration file is to avoid using reflection at runtime.
Let me explain.

I have something like

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract string ID { get; }
}
```

and multiple implementations like

```
public class ClassOne : BaseClass
{
    public override string ID { get { return "Class1"; } }
}

public class ClassTwo : BaseClass
{
    public override string ID { get { return "Class2"; } }
}

public class ClassThree : BaseClass
{
    public override string ID { get { return "Class3"; } }
}
```

What I did in order to be able to use each implementations in their proper context in a static way, is to create for each context a static class like this:

```
namespace ContextOne
{
    internal static class Container
    {
        public static readonly ClassOne = new ClassOne();
    }
}
```

In this way, sharing the BaseClass with all the contexts, I can create multiple children that defines specific values for specific usages. In a context, i can define a .cs file like this:

```
namespace MyContext
{
    public class MyClass : BaseClass
    {
        public override string ID { get { return "MyClass"; } }
    }

    public class YourClass : BaseClass
    {
        public override string ID { get { return "YourClass"; } }
    }

    internal static class Container
    {
        public static readonly MyClass Option1 = new MyClass();
        public static readonly YourClass Option2 = new YourClass();
    }
}
```

I also made a static class in which the static constructor is using reflection to get all the members defined in all the Assemblies of the project so that it can keep an updated internal cache of all these classes associating to them a configuration that is saved on a text file.
The cache is a dictionary in which I use the ID defined in each class as key and a ConfigClass as value.
I disabled the execution of all the code that uses reflection at runtime.
This is a very simplified version of this class:

```
public static class Manager
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ConfigClass> _cache = new Dictionary<string, ConfigClass>();

    static Manager()
    {
        _cache = LoadFile();

        // get a collection of valid IDs defined in the project.
        List<string> validIDs = new List<string>();
        List<Type> containers = GetTypesWithNameInAllAssemblies(".Container", true);
        foreach(var cont in containers)
        {
            MemberInfo[] members = cont.GetMembers(BindingFlag.Static | BindingFlag.Public);
            foreach(var mb in members)
            {
                FieldInfo field = cont.GetField(mb.Name);
                if(field.FieldType.BaseType == typeof(BaseType)
                {

                    //********************* 
                    string id = /* TODO */;
                    //*********************

                    validIDs.Add(id);
                }
            }
        }

        // update the cache.
        AddMissingEntriesToCache(validIDs, _cache);
        RemoveObsoleteEntriesFromCache(validIDs, _cache);
        SaveFile(_cache);
    }

    private static List<Type> GetTypesWithNameInAllAssemblies(string name, bool fullNameEndsWith = false)
    {
        List<Type> wantedTypes = new List<Type>();
        Assembly[] assemblies = GetAssemblies();
        for (int i = 0; i < assemblies.Length; i++)
        {
            Type[] types = assemblies[i].GetTypes();
            for (int j = 0; j < types.Length; j++)
            {
                if (fullNameEndsWith)
                {
                    if (types[j].FullName.EndsWith(name))
                    {
                        wantedTypes.Add(types[j]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (types[j].Name == name)
                    {
                        wantedTypes.Add(types[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return wantedTypes;
    }
}
```

as you can see from the code, I'm not able to get the ID from the FieldInfo object I got with reflection.
I tried using

```
string id = field.GetValue(null) as string;
```

but I'm obviously making a mistake: I probably need to get the static instance of the derived classes defined in the Container in order to do that, but I have no clue on how to do it. Possibly, once the instance is defined, it should stick to the static member so that I will not create other instances causing memory leaks or other sort of issues.

Thank you very much !!   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youve done all the hard work, all this boils down to is needing to get the instance of the class from your static container and then reading the ID:

```
 if(field.FieldType.BaseType == typeof(BaseClass))
 {
    var instance = (BaseClass)field.GetValue(null); // null as this is a static field
                    
    //********************* 
    string id = instance.ID;
    //*********************

    validIDs.Add(id);
 }
```

I've made a cut-down sample of your code to show you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rEjJHw

The `field` in this case was actually the instance of the class, not the ID property which is why your code didn't work.

If you only created that `ID` property to repeat the class name you could have just done `field.FieldType.Name` and not needed to actually get the instance at all.

Comment: thank you for your answer: it worked !!  :)
at the beginning I actually used the ID as the Type.Name, but it was impractical because of the usage I'm doing internally of the ID: it's not just for the dictionary.
anyway, many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, ID is fixed for the class and all instances of class ClassOne share same ID - so actually ID should be not a property of the class, but some meta-information.

If so, you should create IDAttribute and mark your classes with it.
You can still have ID property in BaseClass, which will fetch ID from the attribute.

Comment: hello and thanks for your answer.
your approach is really interesting indeed, although it's not applicable to my case for 2 reasons:
(1) this mechanic is going to be included in a library, therefore, I need to force the people that defines the instances of the BaseClass to define an ID. can you force the definition of an attribute in a derived class?
(2) the ID is used at runtime internally and it's not just for the Dictionary, therefore, using the attribute means that I still have to cache it at runtime. seen that all this is made to avoid reflection, it would be pointless.